# Convert this javascript array to java

Tags: javascript, java, libgdx

I created a multi-dimensional array in JavaScript on a very old project, and I now have moved on from JS and got interested in Java. I'm developing a LibGDX game and I need this array in java format, but I'm not sure how.

```
var merchants = [{
  name : 'Weapons Merchant',
  items : [
    {type: "weapon", cost: 250, name: "Claymore"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 75,  name: "Dagger"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 350, name: "Magic Staff"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 150, name: "Sword"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 125, name: "Bow"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 125, name: "Crossbow"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 5,   name: "Arrow"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 15,  name: "Bolt"}
  ]
}, {
  name : 'Armor Merchant',
  items : [
    {type: "clothing", slot: "head",     name: "Helmet"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "head",     name: "Hood"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "chest",    name: "Chestplate"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "chest",    name: "Tunic"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "chest",    name: "Robe"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "leggings", name: "Legplates"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "leggings", name: "Leggings"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "leggings", name: "Undergarments"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "feet",     name: "Boots"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "feet",     name: "Armored Boots"}
  ]
},  {
  name: 'Material Merchant',
  items:  [
    {type: "material", name: "Leather", cost: 25},
    {type: "material", name: "Iron", cost: 50},
    {type: "material", name: "Steel", cost: 75},
    {type: "material", name: "Mythril", cost: 100},
    {type: "material", name: "Dragonbone", cost: 200}
  ]
}];
```

How can I convert that to Java?

**Note**

Due to a bug with my mobile AIDE, I have to create a 1d array like this:

```
public static List<CharSequence> intro = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
intro.add("multiple add statements with strings");
final CharSequence[] introItems = intro.toArray(new CharSequence[intro.size()]);
        return introItems[number];
```

Since it says `String[][] array = new String[5][5]` has the error "Unexpected end of declaration", so I'd prefer an answer with the format I use, if possible.

Comment: The problem is, we don't know how you're going to store the data. In this javascript code, each element is an object which has different attributes. But with Java, you have to make the classes that each object will represent. Or, you could just store everything in Strings. What do you plan on doing?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the data slightly into pure JSON, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) can do this.  I also don't know how you're reading in the JS/JSON data, so I'll assume that you manage to get it stored into a String in the parsing code:

***jsonString***

```
[{
  name : 'Weapons Merchant',
  items : [
    {type: "weapon", cost: 250, name: "Claymore"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 75,  name: "Dagger"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 350, name: "Magic Staff"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 150, name: "Sword"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 125, name: "Bow"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 125, name: "Crossbow"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 5,   name: "Arrow"},
    {type: "weapon", cost: 15,  name: "Bolt"}
  ]
}, {
  name : 'Armor Merchant',
  items : [
    {type: "clothing", slot: "head",     name: "Helmet"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "head",     name: "Hood"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "chest",    name: "Chestplate"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "chest",    name: "Tunic"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "chest",    name: "Robe"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "leggings", name: "Legplates"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "leggings", name: "Leggings"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "leggings", name: "Undergarments"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "feet",     name: "Boots"},
    {type: "clothing", slot: "feet",     name: "Armored Boots"}
  ]
},  {
  name: 'Material Merchant',
  items:  [
    {type: "material", name: "Leather", cost: 25},
    {type: "material", name: "Iron", cost: 50},
    {type: "material", name: "Steel", cost: 75},
    {type: "material", name: "Mythril", cost: 100},
    {type: "material", name: "Dragonbone", cost: 200}
  ]
}]
```

**Merchant.Java**

```
public class Merchant {
    private String name;
    private List<Item> items;
    /* Getters/Setters */
}
```

**Item.Java**

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String slot;
    private int cost;
    /* Getters/Setters */
}
```

***Parsing Code***

```
// Read in the String using whatever means is appropriate.
String jsonString = ...;

// Parse using Jackson
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Merchant> list = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(
    jsonString,
    Merchant[].class
);
```

If you want the data left as an array, just leave out the **Arrays.asList()** call.

If you can't modify the code to JSON, you can use [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) to parse old JS code.